# Cannot Create Collection in Solr

Tags: java, apache, solr, lucene

So, I am pretty new with solr. I downloaded the distribution and start with the quick start tutorial here -> http://lucene.apache.org/solr/quickstart.html.

When I run

```
bin/solr start -e cloud -noprompt
```

The solr instances were started properly but the getting started collection failed to be created. I keep on getting this:

```
ERROR: Failed to create collection 'gettingstarted' due to: {10.0.0.11:8983_solr=org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException:IOException occured when talking to server at: http://10.0.0.11:8983/solr, 10.0.0.11:7574_solr=org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException:IOException occured when talking to server at: http://10.0.0.11:7574/solr}
```

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Have you checked the logs? A full stacktrace might be more helpful. An IOException can be a result of multiple causes, and without a look at the detailed logs, you won't be able to figure out anything.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue when trying to run Solr in a CentOS VM running under VM Player. The problem disappeared when I restarted the VM in Network Bride mode. 
Hint: Please check host IP configs, if you are trying in a VM.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue when I follow the quick start tutorial, and I resolved this by turning of my VPN. Looks a problem due to Host IP config.